# Get the date of last September

Tags: ms-access, vba

How to I get the **date** of the first day of **last** September?

Example:

- If the date was February 04, 2017 then last September is September 01, 2016
- If the date was November 05, 2017 then last September is September 01, 2017

Comment: What happens on September 01, 2017 and on September 02, 2017 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do with a one-liner:

```
DateSeptemberFirst = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1 + Month(Date) \ 10, 9, 1)
```

Change 10 to 9 if "last September" includes the current September.

Note *integer division* with a backslash.

Comment: I *knew* my solution was kinda clumsy. :)

Answer (score 1):

`DateSerial` is your friend.

```vb
Function LastSeptemberOne() As Date

    Dim lYear As Long

    If Date > DateSerial(Year(Date), 9, 1) Then
        lYear = Year(Date)
    Else
        lYear = Year(Date) - 1
    End If

    LastSeptemberOne = DateSerial(lYear, 9, 1)

End Function
```

You haven't defined what should happen on Sept 01 - you may need to change `>` to `>=`.